# Nuxtjs This dependency was not found: regenerator-runtime/runtime.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/mixins/fetch.client.js

Tags: nuxt.js, ant-design-vue

I introduced the antd vue component when I created the project, and removed it later, but I got an error when I ran it. If I install it again, the error will go away, but I don't want to use this component any more. How do I remove it correctly

Comment: Hi, could you please give more context here? Pretty hard to understand what is your setup here.

Comment: @kissuThank you very much for your attention. I have solved the problem.I installed the dependency regenerator-runtime  as prompted,then came a familiar problem.After I installed a lower version of less-Loader, this problem was resolved. Rerun the program did not report an error.

Comment: could you please show your `package.json` ? try to delete `node_modules` folder and  npm lock file, reinstall your packages via yarn instead of npm

Comment: @DengSihan I mean, if you're moving from NPM, rather go PNPM at that point.

Comment: @DengSihan Thank you for your answer. I tried this,I installed the dependency regenerator-runtime as prompted,then came a familiar problem and after I installed a lower version of the less-Loader, the problem was resolved. Rerun the program did not report an error

Comment: @kissu Could I ask you some questions about using router in Nuxt.js

Comment: Yep, feel free to post another question!

Comment: @kissu  I just started reading this official document, and I haven't figured out how to use it yet. I think IT will take me a little more time to accurately ask the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Leeqi7 yep, please make an effort when posting your question if you don't want it to be closed. Also, please post your answer below, and mark is as accepted since you solved it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

`npm install regenerator-runtime`
If there is a problem like this, **"TypeError: this.getOptions is not a functionat Object.lessLoader"**.Uninstall the current less-loader and install a lower version.